# Titan Black vs 2x970 rendering far too slow

Tags: rendering

Was wondering why my renderings at work were so slow, so I decided to compare the same file with my machine at home and was struck by the difference. ie at work I have a TitanBlack and it took 4 minutes to render 
[image]

( https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVYbw.jpg )

, while at home it took 40 seconds

[image]
( https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWf7V.jpg ).

I know there should be a difference of about double the time going off these benchmarks http://blenchmark.com/gpu-benchmarks but 40 seconds compared to 4 minutes is a big leap especially when rendering for animations.

Any reason why this is happening? The specs for both machines are below (sorry I'm not much of a hardware man)...

Work (Win7): Titan Black
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7BvA.jpg

Home (Win10): 970x2
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHhfz.jpg

Comment: Windows is just inefficient at managing memory. It always has been. Check what;s loaded while trying to render. Also the system setups might be very different, causing memory management to be different on the two machines.

Answer (score 2):

There was a recent rendering issue with the 9xx series cards on Win10. You can find out more on the bug report page.

https://developer.blender.org/T45093

You should be able to get better performance with updated nvidia drivers for windows, and the most recent builds of blender.

Comment: ok I'll give that a look and get back to you.

Comment: I'm such an idiot!

I started recording all my rendering times with different tile sizes and was thinking, gee these are rendering really slow when the tiles are large just like when you render with the CPU... hmm maybe I haven't turned on GPU rendering....

HEADSLAP!!!

So now I'm rendering with GPU with these results:

128x128: (01:10)

240x270: (00:55)

256x256: (00:54)

300x200: (00:54)

600x400: (00:56)

1024x555: (01:25)

Thanks guys for putting up with my lunacy :) 

Should I still be worried though that the TitanBlack is still not faster than my 2 970's?